# How to carry or transport a pet parrot in Indian Railway

Tags: parrots, house-moving

I have three parrots, I have to move to another state. How can I carry parrots in Indian Railway?

Specifically, which type of cage or food is required, or else what do I have to do. How can I care for my parrots (physically and mentally) during the journey?

Note: I [asked about the procedure](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47478/how-to-carry-parrots-in-indian-railway), which documents are required (I heard that I had to get a certificate from the High Court), and things like that at Travel.SE.

Comment: It's not just for Travel.SE . The Indian trains can get very crowded, right? That may be upsetting for the birds - it may be useful if there are ways to comfort them during the journey.

Comment: Only the unreserved coaches are get crowded But reserved coaches are good for pets too  main points is about laws and rule that Birds(Parrot) are   are allowed or not. if allowed then what are the condition to carry them @VixenPopuli

Comment: The related question [Travel.SE](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/47478/how-to-carry-parrots-in-indian-railway) should get an answer about legalities. Here at Pets.SE we should be providing an answer that is Parrot centered about train travel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**"Yes Parrots are Banned in Indian Railways"**

On asking to officials they replied that carrying parrots are illegal in Indian trains, So you can't carry parrots in Indian Railways.

It is good to banned on parrot trade,

[image]